# Gradle build failed while adding firebase ML Kit dependancies

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am using the latest version of firebase libraries but when i add ml kit libraries in `app.gradle` file
The below one.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language:21.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-languagetranslate-model:20.0.6'
```

The project synced successfully
But when i build project i get following error

> manifest merger failed : attribute application@appcomponentfactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.corecomponentfactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   androidmanifest.xml:22:18-91 is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] androidmanifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.corecomponentfactory). suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appcomponentfactory"' to  element
>   at androidmanifest.xml:14:5-135:19 to override.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question.

Add this line in your manifest file

> suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appcomponentfactory"' to element at androidmanifest.xml:14:5-135:19 to override.

The attribute `android.support.v4.app.corecomponentfactory` of Support Library is conflicting with `androidx.core.app.corecomponentfactory` of Androidx. You need to override this. Happy Codding.